# What is the purpose of a dijit LayoutContainer

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I have seen some dojo apps at work that utilize layoutContainers but I have not found much in the way of justification for using said cotainers. What is the purpose of a dijit LayoutContainer? Does it provide orginization for widgets, and|or other benefits? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely start by reading the docs on both [`dijit/layout/LayoutContainer`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/LayoutContainer.html) and a popular subclass, [`dijit/layout/BorderContainer`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html#dijit-layout-bordercontainer), and the most commonly-used widget *inside* of `LayoutContainer`, [`dijit/layout/ContentPane`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html). From the docs:

> This widget is a container partitioned into up to five regions: left (or leading), right (or trailing), top, and bottom with a mandatory center to fill in any remaining space.

You use `LayoutContainer` to lay out related widgets. There is a great section on usage in the `ContentPane` docs, including the following:

> You can use content panes by themselves, but usually you will place content panes inside of a layout container. For example, in a tabbed layout, content pane tags surround each tab of information.

One great use of `LayoutContainers` that I take advantage of is the automatic startup and resizing of widgets inside said containers.

Comment: Thanks, those documents are where my question stemmed from, it seemed that one could position widgets with css rather than add a LayoutContainer (the layoutcontainer seemed similar to a frame, and the container might be unecessary). I could see how resizing has benefits.

Comment: I usually think of `LayoutContainer` as more for organizing `dijit`s than organizing the DOM (like a frame or other HTML container).